# What is a solution with n log(n) runtime for finding if a specific number occupies over half an array

Tags: java, runtime, big-o

The requirements of a program is to print the number that occurs over n/2 times in an array. Make sure the solution's algorithm has a run time of n log(n).

[2, 1, 3, 2] = No result
[1, 5, 2, 5, 5] = 5

My current solution:

```
    int answer = -1;
    int[] a = {2, 4, 2, 5, 1};
    int[] occurances = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
        occurances[a[i]]++;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < occurances.length; i++){
        if(occurances[i] > ((double)a.length)/2){
            answer = i;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(answer);
```

In regards to this, what is the run time of my solution? I don't think that is n log(n) because it only passes through the array once.

If it isn't n log(n), what would be a solution that would have the n log(n)?
If it is, why is it n long(n)?

Comment: `int[] a = {-2, -2, -2, -3};` should return what?

Comment: Sort it (*O(N log(N))*) and scan it (*O(N)*). Still *O(N log(N))*. The cast to `double` is pointless.

Comment: -2, in theory. I only gave enough to solve the basic problem, assuming it was positive integers since all of the examples only gave positive numbers.

Comment: So what about `{10000000000,1000000000,1000000000,...}`? In general you can't use an array-based approach.

Comment: Your solution is O(n), but you need to use a `HashMap<Integer,Integer>` if you don't want your array to be super huge for handling large numbers.

Comment: * "occurrences"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution depends on the max value in the array, so it is *pseudo-polynomial*, i.e. O(n + MAX), where `MAX` is the highest value in the array.

To see if there is a value that occupies more than half of the array you can follow this algorithm:

- Sort the array
- If a value occupies more than half of the array, it is going to occupy the middle cell of a sorted array (see [Pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle#The_birthday_problem)); take the middle element, and use it in the step below
- Use binary search to find the lower and the upper indexes of the range containing the middle element
- Compare the difference between the upper and the lower indexes of the middle element to half the length of the array
- If index difference is more than half the length, the middle element is contained more than half the time; otherwise, the answer is "no".

Another alternative is to use counting in a hash table:

- Construct a hash table that maps an element to element count in O(n)
- Walk the hash table, and take the highest count in O(n)

Comment: This confirmed what I thought was the runtime. I'm trying to explain it to a bunch of students for a final, but I wasn't sure is sorting, then passing through it again would yield a O(n log n). I thought it would still be O(n log n + n), but that still is only n log n.

Comment: @Xenorosth You can do it in O(n) amortized time (tree set step is unnecessary). O(n + n * long n) is the same as O(n * (log n + 1)) which is the same as O(n log n).

Comment: Heck, you can even do a sequential scan of the sorted data to find the count of each value, and stop if a count reached half array size. That would still be _O(n log n)_. But I like the binary search. --- However, as you indicated, a `HashMap` solution is even better, since that is _O(n)_. You should probably highlight that a bit more.

Comment: @Andreas Thank you very much!